# Rsyslog - Logging locally with DynFile then sending to remote host

Tags: centos7, rsyslog

I have set up a centos7 box with rsyslog and am sending logs from multiple devices to it.  What i would like to do is first have the logs be stored locally in a custom file/format with date, from-ip.  I have this working with this configuration:

```
$template DynFile,"/var/log/hosts/%$YEAR%\-%$MONTH%\-%$DAY%/%fromhost-ip%.log"

$RuleSet remote

*.\* -?DynFile

$RuleSet RSYSLOG_DefaultRuleset

$ModLoad imudp

$InputUDPServerBindRuleset remote

$UDPServerRun 514
```

What i would like to do now is also send these logs to another remote rsyslog server.

in rsyslog.conf I added this to the forwarding rules

*.*  @@x.x.x.x:514

The logs are logging locally (to the dynamic file) but nothing is being sent to the remote rsyslog server defined in the forwarding rule.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I had to define the remote host directly after you tell rsyslog to write to the DynFile.  So my new config file looks like this:

## /etc/rsyslog.d/00-local-and-remote.conf

$template DynFile,"/var/log/hosts/%$YEAR%-%$MONTH%-%$DAY%/%fromhost-ip%.log"

$RuleSet remote

*.* -?DynFile

*.* @@x.x.x.x:514

$RuleSet RSYSLOG_DefaultRuleset

$ModLoad imudp

$InputUDPServerBindRuleset remote

$UDPServerRun 514